# How to write SQL statements in SAP HANA Scalar User Defined Functions (UDF)?

Tags: sql, hana

I am writing a UDF (User Defined Function) in SAP HANA. I want to use this function in another SQL statement outside.

Example:

I want to write a UDF like

```
func_get_age (in_employee_id)
```

This function takes in `in_employee_id` as an input parameter. Inside the UDF, it performs a lookup on a table for the particular `in_employee_id` and returns the age. So, a SQL goes inside the UDF. Something like

```
SELECT AGE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = in_employee_id
```

Now this Age needs to be returned back as an output which is then consumed by another SQL. Something like

```
SELECT func_get_age(11234) from dummy;
```

My question is

**Is it possible to write SQL inside UDFs in SAP HANA? Again i want the UDF to return a single value rather than a Table. I am not looking for Table Functions.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly possible in current HANA releases.

For example:

```
create or replace function multi (in mult int)
returns multi_count int
as 
begin
declare cnt integer;

    select count(*) into cnt 
    from objects;

    multi_count := :cnt * :mult;
end;
```

This function takes the number of all visible objects and multiplies it with the input parameter value. The result of this operation is assigned to the RETURN parameter `multi_count`.

```
select multi (3) from dummy;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure
You can create [user-defined scalar function on HANA database](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/hana-database-sqlscript-function-for-fullname.aspx) as given in the sample where fullname of the employee is returned

I copy a simplified version of the HANA UDF function below

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnGetFullname (
 firstName VARCHAR(40),
 middleName VARCHAR(40),
 lastName VARCHAR(40)
)
returns fullname VARCHAR(120)
AS
BEGIN

fullname := CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(firstName, ' '), CONCAT(middleName,' ')),lastName);

END
```

You just assign a value to the return value

Here how you can use the function

```
select fnGetFullname('Sith Lord','Darth','Vader') from dummy;
```